# How to define process.env.ENV in create-react-app?

Tags: ecmascript-6, environment-variables, create-react-app

With the version `1.0.5` of the `create-react-app` boilerplate I've started receiving the fallowing warning:
`*** process.env.ENV is not defined, assuming 'prod' env`

I know how to create a custom environmental variables, but those require `REACT_APP_` prefix.

Now, I've discovered that the message is being shown because of the Chrome's `Grammarly` extension, and disabling it removes the message.

However, I'd like to know how I can resolve this regardless of the extensions.

I know that there are 2 more questions like this on the StackOverflow, but they include solutions that are using the Webpack. Unfortunately, I have no access to the Webpack, since I haven't ejected the create-react-app, and I don't plan to anytime soon.

**Is there a way to declare the environment on `process.env.ENV` in `create-react-app`?**

EDIT:

This was the main question. Is it technically possible to define it in the **non-ejected** `create-react-app`?

Comment: This is an error coming from the Grammarly extension it's got nothing to do with react boilerplate. I also have the same error showing in Chrome and I also use the Grammarly extension but I don't use react.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\*\*\* process.env.ENV is not defined, assuming 'prod' env](//stackoverflow.com/q/44939302)

Comment: Have raised the issue via the contact form on [Grammarly Support](https://support.grammarly.com) it's [Request #1253047](https://support.grammarly.com/hc/en-us/requests/1253047).

Comment: Great @lankymart!
Thanks everyone for chipping in. We'll then just have to wait for Grammarly to resolve it. 

Cheers,
Nemanja

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\*\*\* process.env.ENV is not defined, assuming 'prod' env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939302/process-env-env-is-not-defined-assuming-prod-env)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grammarly extension is the cause of this not React. Have logged a request with Grammarly Support and this is the result

> Hailey (Grammarly Support)
>   Jul 6, 11:33 PM PDT
>
> Hi Lankymart,
>
> Thank you for contacting Grammarly Customer Support!
>
> Please rest assured that the technical team is aware of the problem and they are currently working on it.
>
> Unfortunately, this will not be a quick fix and I cannot provide you with an estimated timeframe, as the developers will need some time to analyze the cause of this issue.
>
> I’m going to close this case, but if you have further information regarding this issue, please reply to this email and the case will be re-opened for further investigation. We apologize for any inconvenience caused.
>
> Best wishes,
>   Hailey
>
> ---
>
> Lankymart
>   Jul 6, 12:49 PM PDT
>
> The console window in Chrome is constantly showing the warning - "process.env.ENV is not defined" turning off the extensions removes the error, it is not related a specific website. Already on the internet threads are popping up with people reporting the same issue and the common thread is Grammarly. Has a bug been introduced into the extension perhaps?
>
> Evidence:
>
> https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2722#issuecomment-313017403
>   [How to define process.env.ENV in create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44919392/692942)
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/44940512/692942
>
> Website URL:
>   No specific URL issue is a extension bug.

Comment: Apparently, it has now been fixed, but you need to uninstall then download the latest extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-spell-checker-g/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen

Comment: I can confirm that the problem no longer exists.