# *** process.env.ENV is not defined, assuming 'prod' env

Tags: angularjs, environment-variables, jhipster, microservices, gateway

I am unable to open My JHipster + Angular 2 (Gateway) Application home page with port 8080 (which is given at server port in `application-dev.yml`) and
Getting following exception in console

```
*** process.env.ENV is not defined, assuming 'prod' env
```

The Same application is running fine on port 9000 (which is given by yarn) and giving exception like below in console.

```
process.env.ENV is not defined, assuming 'prod' env
chrome-extension://kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen/src/js/bundle.js:4776 ***
```

My problem is if I use 9000 port (Given by yarn) unable to communicate with other microservices applications.

Why am I getting the above exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The above warning is not coming from your app. It is actually coming from one of the chrome extension (Grammarly for Chrome). Disabling the extension solved problem!!

check this https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2722

Comment: after disable Grammarly exception is gone but still my home page is not displaying

Comment: Have raised the issue via the contact form on [Grammarly Support](https://support.grammarly.com) it's [Request #1253047](https://support.grammarly.com/hc/en-us/requests/1253047).

Comment: Apparently, it has now been fixed, but you need to uninstall then download the latest extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-spell-checker-g/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen