# Webpack not recognising values defined by DefinePlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

When webpack bundles and I launch the website, I get the following error:

> *** process.env.ENV is not defined, assuming 'prod' env

However, if I log my process.env

`Object {NODE_ENV: "development", ENV: "development", HOST: "localhost"}`

My webpack configuration:

```
/*  Main */
const webpackConfig = {
  entry: [
    project.app.entry,
  ],
  output: {
    path: project.path.out,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
      rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: project.path.app,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'babel-loader' },
          { loader: 'eslint-loader' },
        ],
      }],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
        ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),// Added because webpack bundle complains
        HOST: JSON.stringify(process.env.HOST),
      },
    }),
  ],
  devtool: DEV ? 'source-map' : false,
  resolve: {
    modules: ["src", "node_modules"],
    alias: {}
  }
};
```

Is this a bug in webpack, or am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the Grammarly extension? People are having same issue due to that: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2722 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939302/process-env-env-is-not-defined-assuming-prod-env https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919392/how-to-define-process-env-env-in-create-react-app

Comment: Yes it was exatly that, thank you @yuriy636. Feel free to post it as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people are having the same issue because of the **Grammarly** extension.

If you are using it, disable it and the error will be gone.

---

Related:

[How to define process.env.ENV in create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919392/how-to-define-process-env-env-in-create-react-app)

[*** process.env.ENV is not defined, assuming 'prod' env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939302/process-env-env-is-not-defined-assuming-prod-env)

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2722

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be caused by the HotModuleReplacementPlugin for me